# Re: Prove that Riemann integrability implies boundedness.

Tags: real-analysis

There were some miscommunication in the previous post so I'm reposting.

Below is the theorem and the proof from my class. I get stuck when it mentions "Find $P',T', mesh \, P' < \delta$..." Also, where the heck did $|f(t_j' - f(t_j)| \Delta x > 2\epsilon$ come from?

Can someone explain step by step? Thank you so much!

Theorem: Let $f \in R[a,b]$. Then $f$ is bounded.

Proof: The integrability of $f$ implies $I = \int_a^b f(x)dx$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $\delta >0$ such that for any partition pair $P,T$ with $mesh \, P < \delta$, $|R(f,P,T)-I| < \epsilon$. Suppose $f$ unbounded. Find $P',T', mesh \, P' < \delta$ such that $|R(f,P',T')-I| \ge \epsilon$, which is possible since $f$ is unbounded. We know there exists interval $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$ where $f$ unbounded. Let $P'=P$. Try to change $T$. Pick $t_i' = t_i$ for $i \ne j$. But for $j = i$, let $t_j'$ be such that $|f(t_j') - f(t_j)| \Delta x > 2\epsilon$. Then $P', T'$ gives $|R(f,P',T')-I| > \epsilon$.

Comment: If $f$ is unbounded, then on any partition $P$ there must exist a pair of points $x_i,x_{i+1}$ such that $f$ is unbounded on $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$. Hence $\sup_{x \in [x_i, x_{i+1}]} f(x) = \infty$, and hence $U(f,P) = \infty$. Hence $f$ is not integrable.

Comment: $@$user72625: By the way, I suggest you either start accepting some answers or indicate why the answers you've gotten are not fully satisfactory to you.

Comment: Sorry. The your answer the answer below clarified my question. How do I "accept"?

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is unbounded.

$1$. Show that for any partition $P = \{a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots < x_n = b\}$ of $[a,b]$ and any $M > 0$, one can choose sample points $x_i^* \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$ such that

$|R(f,P,x_i^*)| = |\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f(x_i^*)(x_{i+1}-x_i)| > M.$

(Hint: If $f$ is unbounded on $[a,b]$, it must be unbounded on at least one subinterval $[x_i,x_{i+1}]$.  Choose one such subinterval; pick the sample points in every other subinterval arbitrarily, and then choose the sample point in the fixed unbounded subinterval last of all.)

$2$. Deduce that $f$ cannot be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.